# Is centripetal acceleration the same as angular acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, angular-velocity

I know that the centripetal acceleration changes the direction of the tangential speed. But can I calculate it as the derivative of the angular speed with respect to time? Or are these different things?

Comment: No no no. These are different things, because change in direction of tangential speed is not the same as change in tangential speed.

Comment: @Mike Dunleavy he should be able to if he incorporates radius into his calculations no?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey They are closely related, but not the same.

Comment: @Yogi: Spin a bike wheel, at constant speed, with zero angular acceleration - i.e. just spinning by itself. Pick a point on the tire. Is that point undergoing centripetal acceleration? Yes, because the direction of its velocity reverses every half revolution. Remember, this is with angular acceleration = $0$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and can agree to a degree, but technically speaking can't whatever logic/information that allows us to deduce angular momentum also be categorized as centripetal acceleration?

Comment: The two quantities are definitely not the same. Even if you could relate them by some relationship this does not make them to be the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows very little research effort.

Comment: @YogiDMT *"but technically speaking can't whatever logic/information that allows us to deduce angular momentum also be categorized as centripetal acceleration?"*. So is force and mass or pressure and temperature or velocity and time technically speaking also the same things, because there exist relations between them? We are dealing with two different properties with each their own specific definition.

Comment: @steeven What about my statement do you see as incorrect?

Comment: @YogiDMT I just quoted that part.

Comment: @steeven and why do you think it's incorrect?

Comment: @YogiDMT Excuse me? Angular momentum (or "the logic/information that allows us to deduce" it) cannot be "characterized" as centripetal acceleration. That's what I reacted to.

Comment: Yes i know, and i'm wondering why you think that isn't right. To have angular momentum we must have coordinates that undergo rotational transformations around an axis, isn't that what centripetal acceleration is? I'm not arguing they're the same things, because coordinates of a rigid system don't seem to be subject to the definitions as non-rigid systems but he was also asking whether or not you can derive centripetal acceleration from angular momentum or visa versa, which you should be able to.

Comment: @YogiDMT *"I'm not arguing they're the same things"* Then we agree. And as far as I can see, there is no mention in the question of angular *momentum*.

Comment: Well he did mention angular speed in the question, that's why i brought it up.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this excellent (if naïve) conceptual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not the same, but you can calculate the angular momentum with respect to orbital momentum (centripetal acceleration) and visa versa if you know the rigidness of the system and the radius to the point you are measuring. Any sort of angular momentum always involves some level of centripetal acceleration but centripetal acceleration doesn't always involve angular acceleration because in rigid systems coordinate transformations aren't subject to the same definitions as non-rigid systems for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

They cannot be the same thing because they have different units.  [Centripetal acceleration](http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/physics/circ/node6.html) $a_c = v^2/R = \omega^2 R$ has units of $\rm m/s^{2}$, while [angular acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_acceleration) $\alpha = d\omega/dt$ has units of $\rm \text{radian}/s^2$.

Centripetal acceleration is the component of the acceleration vector that's perpendicular to the velocity, and responsible for changing the direction of the motion.  The component of acceleration parallel (or antiparallel) to the velocity vector, $a_\parallel$, changes the speed but not the direction.  If you're moving in a circle, you can prove pretty easily that $a_\parallel = \alpha R$ relates the angular acceleration $\alpha$ to the [tangential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) acceleration $a_\parallel$.  So $a_\parallel$ and $a_c$ are two orthogonal components of the vector acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not the same. Say we have an object moving in the cartesian plane. We can parameterize it's motion using polar coordinates: 
$$r\langle\cos \theta, \sin \theta\rangle$$

To be clear, $r$ and $\theta$ should be thought of as functions of time. It would be more accurate to write $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, but this would take up too much space.

Consider the velocity of the object:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\big[r\langle\cos \theta, \sin \theta\rangle\big]=\dot{r}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle+r\omega\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle$$

Where $\omega = \dot{\theta}$. Usually, $\omega$ is referred to as the object's angular velocity. Notice that the component of the velocity vector that is tangent to the object's motion has magnitude $r\omega$. This is referred to as tangential velocity.

Now, consider the acceleration of the object: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\big[\dot{r}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle+r\omega\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle\big]$$$$=\ddot{r}\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle+\dot{r}\omega\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle+(\dot{r}\omega+r\alpha)\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle-r\omega^2\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle$$
Where $\alpha=\dot{\omega}=\ddot{\theta}$. Usually, $\alpha$ is referred to as the object's angular acceleration. Let's simplify the above expression: 
$$\left(\ddot{r}-r\omega^2\right)\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta\rangle+\left(2\dot{r}\omega+r\alpha\right)\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta\rangle$$

The component of the acceleration vector perpendicular to the object's motion is called its centripetal acceleration. Notice it has magnitude $\ddot{r}-r\omega^2$.

The component of the acceleration vector tangent to the object's motion is called its tangential acceleration. Notice it has magnitude $2\dot{r}\omega+r\alpha$. If we called the object's angular momentum $L$, then the tangential acceleration is also equal to the following (assuming that the object's mass does not change):

$$\dot{L}\cdot\frac{1}{rm}$$

Comment: Overkill on the mathematics, IMO. If the OP doesn't understand the difference between centripetal and angular acceleration, she's not going to understand this.

Comment: @sammygerbil Sorry about that. I'm new to physics.stackexchange. I came from math.stackexchange.

Comment: "you might as well face it you're addicted to math"!